# Uncertainty in dividing a constant

Tags: error-analysis

In an experiment, let's say we measured wavelength of light and had an uncertainty attached to that wavelength. Suppose we then calculated the frequency using $v=f \lambda$. Since $v$ in this case is a constant my initial impression was that it would follow the same rule as multiplying by a constant - multiplying the uncertainty with that constant but that does not seem correct to me. Is there any other rule to do this correctly or was my initial assumption correct and all that is needed to be done is divide the constant by the uncertainty?

Comment: A good reference that elaborates on the answers provided by Andrew and Semoi is: Data Analysis for Scientists and Engineers by Stuart L Meyer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assume you know $v$ to a much better precision than other sources of uncertainty in your measurement, then you can use a standard [propagation of uncertainty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty) formula

\begin{equation}
\Delta f = \left|\frac{\partial (v/\lambda)}{\partial \lambda }\right|\Delta \lambda = \frac{v}{\lambda^2} \Delta \lambda = f \frac{\Delta \lambda}{\lambda}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $a$ is a constant and $X$ is a random variable. Then one can show that the variance satisfies
$$
Var[aX] = a^2 \;Var[X] = a^2 \sigma^2_X
$$
Also, the standard deviation is defined as $\sigma_{X} = \sqrt{Var[X]}$.

Using your example, we got $X = 1/\lambda$ and $a=v$, and obtain
$$
\tag{1}
Var[f] = Var[v/\lambda] = v^2 Var[1/\lambda] 
$$
Although this is an exact expression, it is most often not useful. Thus, we are usually Taylor expanding around $\lambda=\lambda_0$
$$
f(\lambda) = \frac{1}{\lambda}
\approx f(\lambda_0) + \frac{(\lambda-\lambda_0)}{1!} f^\prime(\lambda_0) + ...
$$
Since constant terms do not contribute to the variance, we obtain
$$
Var[1/X] \approx [f^\prime(x_0)]^2 \cdot Var[X]
$$
We can use this formula and plug it into eq.(1). However, if $\lambda$ follows a standard normal distributed, $1/\lambda$ follows a Cauchy distribution, and $Var[1/\lambda]$ does no exist. So be careful with dividing by a random variable. These expressions become nasty.